# Converting nested list and a list of tuples into a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Lets say I have two lists as follows:

`test_list = [[1,2],[4,5]]`

`lat_long_list = [(2.3,4.5),(5.6,7.8),(9.2,5.3),(8.9,9.0)]`

I want to convert these two lists into a dictionary as follows:

```
test_dict =    {vehicle 0:[
                    {1:{ lat: 2.3,
                         long:4.5,
                         key: 0
                       },
                    {2:{ lat:5.6,
                         long:7.8,
                         key: 1
                       }],
                {vehicle 1:[
                    {4:{ lat: 9.2,
                         long:5.3,
                         key: 2
                       },
                    {5:{ lat:8.9,
                         long:9.0,
                         key: 3
                       }]
                 }
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Where do you stuck in your attempt ?

Comment: Is it a string "vehicle 0", or 0 is sufficent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested dict and list comprehension just for the hell of it:

```
d = {f"vehicle {num}": [{vehicle:{"lat":lat[0],"long":lat[1],"key":num*2+lat_num}}
                        for lat_num, (vehicle, lat) in enumerate(zip(item,lat_long_list[num*2:num*2+2]))]
                        for num, item in enumerate(test_list)}
print (d)

{'vehicle 0': [{1: {'lat': 2.3, 'long': 4.5, 'key': 0}},
               {2: {'lat': 5.6, 'long': 7.8, 'key': 1}}],
 'vehicle 1': [{4: {'lat': 9.2, 'long': 5.3, 'key': 2}},
               {5: {'lat': 8.9, 'long': 9.0, 'key': 3}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `test_list` will contain your keys, and `lat_long_list` your values.

```py
import pprint
test_list = [[1,2],[4,5]]
lat_long_list = [(2.3,4.5),(5.6,7.8),(9.2,5.3),(8.9,9.0)]

#Flatten your keys iterable
keys_list = itertools.chain.from_iterable(test_list)
print(keys_list)
>>> [1, 2, 4, 5]
result = dict([
    (key, value) for key, value in zip(keys_list,lat_long_list)
])
print(result)
>>>{1: (2.3, 4.5), 2: (5.6, 7.8), 4: (9.2, 5.3), 5: (8.9, 9.0)}
```

You might want to check:

- [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function
- [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) utilities

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
test_list = [[1,2],[4,5]]

lat_long_list = [(2.3,4.5),(5.6,7.8),(9.2,5.3),(8.9,9.0)]

fields = ['lat','long','key']
test_dict = {}
ctr = 0
for i,l in enumerate(test_list):
    test_dict['vehicle '+str(i)] = []
    tempd = {}
    for j,l2 in enumerate(l):
        tempd[l2] = dict(zip(fields,list(lat_long_list[i+j+ctr])+[i+j+ctr]))
    ctr+=1
    test_dict['vehicle '+str(i)].append(tempd)

print(test_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'vehicle 0': [{1: {'lat': 2.3, 'long': 4.5, 'key': 0}, 2: {'lat': 5.6, 'long': 7.8, 'key': 1}}], 'vehicle 1': [{4: {'lat': 9.2, 'long': 5.3, 'key': 2}, 5: {'lat': 8.9, 'long': 9.0, 'key': 3}}]}
```